# fgetcsv escape comma in string

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have this code:

```
if (($handle = fopen($url, 'r')) !== FALSE){
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)) !== FALSE){
            $test = explode(";", $row[0]);
                 $data[] = array(
                'item' => $test[0],
                'description' => $test[1] 
                );
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

and this is my csv:

```
200        pc thing, another
```

but when i print_r the data array, the description is this: **pc thing**
everything behind the comma isn't there.. Why is this happening? my output should be: **pc thing, another**

How can i solve this?

Comment: why do you need to `explode` using semicolon as parameter? do a `print_r($row)` to see what you have there and use the `$row` array

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you're trying to explode a (non-existing) semicolon. Give this code a go:

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$rows = explode("\n",$data);
$data = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $s = str_getcsv($row);
    $data1['item']=> $s[0];
    $data1['description']=> $s[1];
    $data[]=$data1;
}
```